# XML parsing using Perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Parsing with nested tags in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295506/xml-parsing-with-nested-tags-in-perl)

In the following xml structure. i need to parse the magnitudes lower and upper values in perl and  need to  parse the type attribute in the children tags

```
<definition>
    <attributes>
        <children>
            <attributes>
                <children xsi:type="C_COMPLEX_OBJECT" >
                    <attributes>
                        <children>
                            <attributes>
                                <children><list><magnitude><lower>100</lower><upper>200</upper></magnitude></list></children>
                                <children><list><magnitude><lower>200</lower><upper>400</upper></magnitude></list></children>
                                <children><list><magnitude><lower>400</lower><upper>750</upper></magnitude></list></children>
                                <children><list><magnitude><lower>250</lower><upper>500</upper></magnitude></list></children>
                                <children><list><magnitude><lower>350</lower><upper>1000</upper></magnitude></list></children>
                            </attributes>
                        </children>
                    </attributes>
                </children>
               <children></children>
            </attributes>
        </children>
    </attributes>
</definition>
```

Comment: you can use xPath with XML parsing to retrieve the require information. let me know if you need a code for it. you can consider XML-Twig and libxml for xml parsing.

Comment: you have already asked same question in the previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295506/xml-parsing-with-nested-tags-in-perl

Comment: @Nikil solution for that question is solved this is another that we cant resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small code using LibXML to parse this xml and get the required values.

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml = $parser->parse_file('test.xml');

my @lower = $xml->find('//lower');
my @upper = $xml->find('//upper');

my $type = $xml->find('//children/@type');
```

the @lower, @upper, $type are the nodes. to extract the string please call the to_lietral sub. e.g. $type->to_literal.

Comment: thanks for the reply, all the children node has lower and upper node. We identified that the 5th children node has the required lower and upper value. Above code retreived all the values

Comment: @Thangaraj- please vote it if this is helpful to you:)